Double Opt-in Implementation and Adding Contact to List via Marketing Automation
We are in the process of implementing a Double Opt-in workflow within our Sitecore 10.3 environment. To begin, we aim to add a contact to a newly created contact list upon form submission, prior to them confirming their subscription.
We have taken the following steps using the Marketing Automation feature:
Marketing Automation Plan:
Created a new automation plan in Sitecore Launchpad > Marketing Automation.
Added a Form Submission Trigger to initiate the plan upon form submission.
Included an action to Add Contact to List, using a pre-existing contact list.
Activated the automation plan after configuration.
Linking Automation Plan to the Form:
In the Forms Designer, selected the Submit button.
In Submit Actions, added the action to trigger the Form Submission Goal.
However, after completing these steps, the expected outcome is not occurring—the contact is not being added to the specified list when the form is submitted.
Could you please assist in identifying any missing configurations or overlooked steps? Additionally, if there is an out-of-the-box solution for implementing Double Opt-in (user subscription) with minimal to no customization, we would appreciate guidance on that as well.
Thank you in advance for your support.
